# Not understanding why this AngularJS works without having to $inject service

Tags: angularjs

I'm confused as to why the below code works even though I have not injected the custom service.  I don't get when you have to inject and when you do not.

http://plnkr.co/edit/aCpIYleNL4p9IRA0aAzr?p=preview

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular.module('svccApp', []);

angular.module('svccApp').
factory('bareService', [

  function() {
    var myValue = {};
    myValue.str1 = 'xyz';
    return myValue;
  }
]);

angular.module('svccApp')
  .controller('MyController', MyController);

// WHY IS THIS NOT NECESSARY?
//MyController.$inject = ['$scope', 'bareService'];

function MyController($scope, bareService) {
  $scope.testVal = bareService.str1;
}

  }());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular is smart enough to look at the names of the parameters of your Controller and figure out what needs to be injected. However you need to manually specify the things you want to inject as strings (e.g. `MyController.$inject = ['$scope', 'bareService'];`) if you minify your code because the parameter names will be mangled.

For example, this:

```
function MyController($scope, bareService) {
  $scope.testVal = bareService.str1;
}
```

might be minified into this:

```
function MyController(a, b) {
  a.testVal = b.str1;
}
```

Which would break dependency injection.

Comment: I've seen references to the minimize problem.  I also have noticed that there are some packages (like ngmin) that somehow address this issue.  I have a couple worries.  1) what is considered best practice?  2) if I follow the guideline to make my code minim proof by explicitly mentioning injectables, I can't easily test.   I'm new at this, what do most seasoned angular dev's do?

Comment: I personally like using ng-annotate (an alternative to ngMin) but it doesn't work in all cases. The line you had commented out is perfectly valid too. It shouldn't make testing any harder. If you are looking for best pratcices here is a style guide that addresses the issue https://github.com/johnpapa/angularjs-styleguide#minification-and-annotation

Comment: Thanks rob.  I'll add ngmin.  I have a small mind and like things to be clear.  not working "all the time" worries me. I'll try to always add my dependencies and have enough tests of my minimized to catch the errors (hopefully)

Comment: I wonder if there is a way to tell Angular not to be so smart and force me to make my injectables correct? Do you know if that is possible?

Comment: ng-min is actually deprecated and you should use ng-annotate instead. If you're using Angular 1.3 you can initialize your app like this: `<div ng-app="myApp" ng-strict-di>` and it won't try to inject anything from your parameter names

Comment: thanks rob.  I'm in the midst of trying to write a gulp.diff() that will tell me if ng-annotate did anything.  At least that way I have a sanity check on the way through.  diff is giving me grief, but I guess that is to be expected.

Answer (score -1):

You are injecting the service. Replace your named function with an anonymous one:

```
angular.module('svccApp')
  .controller('MyController', function($scope, bareService) {
  $scope.testVal = bareService.str1;
});
```

which is, in practice, the same as what you are doing, and you'll see that it mirrors pretty much any example you'll find of injecting a service into a controller.